# Issue with mb_internal_encoding() function in PHP 8.3 when using Command Line Interface (CLI) - No problem in PHP 8.2

Tags: php

I'm working with PHP 8.3 and have encountered a puzzling issue regarding the `mb_internal_encoding()` function. When using PHP through an Apache web server, everything works seamlessly. However, when I switch to the command line interface (CLI), I receive the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding()
```

Interestingly, I didn't face this problem in PHP 8.2, and it seems like the `mb_internal_encoding()` function is not recognized in the CLI environment with PHP 8.3. I've checked my PHP version, and it's indeed 8.3. Is there something specific I need to configure or enable to make this function available in the CLI as well?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

---

Comment: Your CLI version of PHP is likely compiled without the mbstring extension. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: I don't compile myself (don't have the knowledge). I am using Debian out of the box. It stopped working since I updated from PHP 8.2 to PHP 8.3

Comment: "Debian out of the box" does not provide PHP 8.3, not in the stable version, not in testing, not in unstable. How did you install it? Did you check  whether the extension is enabled?

Comment: I don't remember. I use webmin to handle my updates.

Answer (score 0):

[mb_internal_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) is supported in PHP 8. So, if it fails for you, then you do not have its extension, `php-mbstring` properly installed. You will need to identify which php.ini is being used by your CLI PHP and then make sure this extension is installed and enabled for that, see more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: I already tried ´´sudo apt install php-mbstring´´ but it only says that I am already running the latest version. So far I found out, that Apache runs PHP 8.2.13 (fine) and CLI with 8.3.0 (bug)

Comment: The module is not listet. `php -m | grep mb` returns nothing

Comment: @JuergenSchulze maybe this will help? https://www.linuxtuto.com/how-to-install-php-8-3-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some trouble with Debian and PHP 8.3

Anyways. I switched back to PHP 8.2.13

`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2`

Now mb_internal_encoding is workling again.

And `php -m | grep mb`

returns

> mbstring

as expected